# Bootstrap 4 make elements center vertically in sticky-top class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

What I tried to achieve is make elements center in `div` with `sticky-top` class, I used these class to get this but no success:

```
d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#element-1 {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#element-2 {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8" id="element-1">
    Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content 
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="element-2">
      <div class="sticky-top">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
          <div>I should be center vertically</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see element not center in vertical, this what I want to get, <strike>and don't want to get centered elements inline, they should be under each other.</strike>

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** here is photoshop version of my goal:

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand why you have used "sticky-top", but have you tried to add the classes that you have mentioned above along with the "col-4" ?

I mean instead of "col-4"  => "col-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `h-100` class to sticky-top and its inner div.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#element-1 {
  background: lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
}

#element-2 {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8" id="element-1">
    Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content 
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="element-2">
      <div class="sticky-top h-100">
        <div class="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center flex-column">
          <div class="text-center">I should be center vertically</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also remove sticky-top inner div, if it is not necessary for you:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#element-1 {
  background: lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
}

#element-2 {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8" id="element-1">
    Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content 
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="element-2">
      <div class="sticky-top d-flex h-100 justify-content-center flex-column">
          <div class="text-center">I should be center vertically</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1** Sorry, I had not noticed the sticky problem

I used second solution adding:

```
.sticky-top{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#element-1 {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#element-2 {
  background: gray;
}
.sticky-top{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8" id="element-1">
    Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content 
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="element-2">
      <div class="sticky-top d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
          <div class="text-center">I should be center vertically</div>
          <div class="text-center">I should be center vertically</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No my friend, both demo are not `sticky` and their lost sticky. also see your demo in `Full page` version

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand the requirements, but is this what you want?

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#element-1 {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#element-2 {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8" id="element-1">
    Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content Some Content 
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="element-2">
      <div class="sticky-top">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          I should be in center
           </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          I should be in center too!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: The only difference i did was add the text in its own div

```
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          I should be in center
         </div>
         <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          I should be in center too!
         </div>
```

Comment: No my friend, `I should be in center` should vertically center

Comment: Do you have an example of the kind of thing you want?

Comment: Can you please not downvote my answer, its not fair giving downvote when I only answered what I could from your poor description

Comment: I don't think it's a poor description, when I told want to `vertically center` and used `justify-content-center align-items-center` so what is it mean? I want center align, then I added a image, so what? If you can solve it so update your post or if not so delete it.

Comment: If it wasn't a poor description then you wouldnt update your answer.

And you said "and don't want to get centered elements inline, they should be under each other."..which is what I did. That's not what you wanted, therefor poor description.

Comment: I edited my question and you posted this answer exactly in a same time. I found solution myself and made it strike. anyway, your answer not a solution for my main problem.

Comment: But I answered your question based on what I believed to be the problem based on what you said. It's ok that its nt the right answer, but its completely unacceptable to down vote the answer. I lose points because of that!